# What are all the stereoisomers of 1-ethyl-3-methylcyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, stereochemistry, cyclohexane

What are all the stereoisomers of 1-ethyl-3-methylcyclohexane? The following image shows my attempt to answer the question. But I am not sure if I am correct.

[image]

Note: I am treating this cyclohexane as flat since it's confomers interconvert rapidly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, your answer seems right ... but you should think of other abbreviations for ethyl and methyl groups.

$\hskip2.5in$[image]

Strictly there are eight missing hydrogens per structure that you should add for clarification: three for each methyl- and five for each ethyl-group. C or C$_2$ is not a common (and as for C$_2$ not a good*) abbreviation for such groups ... Me and Et or CH$_3$ and C$_2$H$_5$ would be more usual.

---

* e.g., C$_2$ could be $\ce{-C#CH}$ or $\ce{-CH=CH2}$

Comment: You forgot $\ce{-CH3}$ :P

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Wavy bonds ~~~